# python tkinter, failed to execute script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Выскочила ошибка **failed to execute script**

Пытался решить - но не вышло, в интернете были видео на эту тему - но картинки будут лежать месте

Сама программа прекрасно работает - но после компиляции всегда выдавала выдавала ошибку

**Ошибка:**

```
failed to execute script
```

**Код:**

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window['background'] = '#131313'
image = Canvas(window, width=370,height=500)
window.iconbitmap('avatar.ico')
background = PhotoImage(file='forceq.png')
image.create_image(0, 0, image=background,anchor=NW)
window.title("LegitSnake v0.48")
window.geometry('370x500')
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

image.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/UnwelcomeQuietCommunication

Comment: ну у меня споткнулось на иконке - если закоментировать строку с iconbitmap, то остальное работает.
Проблема решена здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860325/python-3-tkinter-iconbitmap-error-in-ubuntu
Там вместо формата *.ico используется  формат *.xbm.